# How to initialize NSString to NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsmutablestring

Is there any way to initialize NSString to NSMutableString? and also reverse order?

```
-(void)st:(NSString *)st
{
  NSMutableString str = st; // gives warning..
  NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`NSString` is an immutable representation (or a readonly view at worst).  So you would need to either cast to a `NSMutableString` if you know it's mutable or make a mutable copy:

```
-(void)st:(NSString *)st
{
  NSMutableString *str =  [[st mutableCopy] autorelease];
  NSLog(@"string: %@", str);
}
```

I autoreleased it because `mutableCopy` returns a newly initialized copy with a retain count of 1.

Comment: I don't know if this will work how it is, but the NSMutableString should be a pointer NSMutableString *str =  [[st mutableCopy] autorelease];

Answer (score 4):

You can set an NSMutableString to an NSString, but not the other way around

```
NSString *str =  [NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

is okay, but

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

is not. This is because an NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString, so it 'is a' NSString.
You can however create a mutable string from an NSString with

```
NSMutableString *mStr = [str mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *someImmutableString = @"something";
NSMutableString *mutableString = [someImmutableString mutableCopy];
```

**Important!** `mutableCopy` returns an object that you own, so you must either release or autorelease it.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 2.0

For Swift users, the following works in Xcode 7.

```
var str : String = "Regular string"
var mutableStr : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: str)
```